# How to make an HTTP app HTTPS with HAProxy and SSL Termination

Tags: ssl, https, haproxy, system-administration

Where I work theres an web app that is hosted on windows servers, all users access the application using HTTP, not HTTPS. This is due to some restrictions that the dev team could not solve.

So I thought that i could solve this issue using HAProxy and SSL Termination, so the users would communicate with the proxy first using HTTPs and then the proxy would communicate with the app servers using HTTP. This would be inside a private VLAN so the HTTP traffic cannot be sniffed.

The users access the app using this schema --> http://servername:port/path/to/app

So instead of this, the users should type https://haproxy.domainname:port/path/to/app
and the haproxy should handle the communication against the app servers.

Is this possible? or should i think of another solution to this?

I came up with this:

```
frontend haproxy.domain.name
    bind ipaddress:port ssl crt /home/cert.pem
    acl is_bdc path -i -m beg /path/to/app
    use_backend web_servers if is_bdc
    default_backend web_servers

backend web_servers
        balance roundrobin
        server server1 ipaddress:port
```

I can access the app server using this configuration, but the app fills some variables using the URL of the web browser, and as im accessing the app using another URL (haproxy.domain.name instead of the app server hostname) its causing some errors. Is possible to maintain the app server hostname on the url but also keep the SSL termination? The used certificate its a wildcard so adding the domain name would be enought (i think)

Thanks you in advance!

Comment: To maintain the hostname haproxy must be run on the system where the hostname points to.

Comment: Steffen, thanks for the info. I will try to install haproxy on one of the app server from the testing environment and i will comment my results.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Well, since HAProxy is not available for windows servers, maybe i can make this work using another reverse proxy?

Comment: Use whatever reverse proxy suites you. Like nginx, apache, iis, ... - nothing special needed here.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Well I managed to use IIS as reverse proxy and most of the apps seem to work, but with some sites i get a browser error of mixing content because some of the content that is requested using HTTPs is served as HTTP. It seems that IIS outbound rewrite rules are not working. Im still trying to figure out why.

Comment: It is usually not seen as the job of the reverse proxy to rewrite the content so that the links fit. This would be pretty hard especially if content is dynamically generated. Instead one should make all links in the site relativ or path-absolute, so that they don't refer to a specific protocol (https vs. https) and domain.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Got it, i will ask the dev team to make all link relativ or path absolute. Maybe we can try this on the testing environment first. I will comment my results as soon as i can.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are several options to solve your issue.

1.) Tell the app server that it runs behind a reverse proxy and configure the app engine to use `haproxy.domain.name` as Domain/Host part, something similar to tomcats [Proxy Support How-To](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/proxy-howto.html)

2.) you can use the [http-response replace-header](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.5/configuration.html#4.2-http-response%20replace-header) or [replace value](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.5/configuration.html#4.2-http-response%20replace-value) to rewrite the URL. This will not work with links in the body of the response.

As you haven't mention the HAProxy version I link to the latest one.
Maybe you will need also to configure the IIS to know that it works behind a reverse proxy, in case you use IIS.